# Set cursor position in react without using mouse or touchpad?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tensorflow

I am trying to use tensorflow and handpose to navigate my site using my hands. Is there a library/method I can use in order to set the position of the cursor? I can't seem to find anything that allows me to set the cursor position only cursor tracking

Comment: You can't move the cursor from a website.

Comment: Not even with the pointer lock API.

Comment: By the way, your question isn't about [tag:tensorflow], so you shouldn't have that tag on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Cursor is not controlled by a website, why even you need it? Use you can simply get reference to browser dom with the browser api and do whatever, no need of cursor